# Wrong apache configuration. Perl scripts cannot execute

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, perl, cgi

I've got wrong apache configuration. My script don't want to be executed and browser trying to download it as a file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName president.com

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi/

<Directory /var/www/cgi/>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

1. Scripts are own by www-data:www-data with rights 755 and can be
   executed (+x).
2. Shebang e.g. #!/usr/bin/perl.
3. Error log is empty.

How to fix this problem? I need my scripts to be executed

Comment: So what do you want to know? What is your question?

Comment: @RoaldvanDoorn What should I do? How to make my scripts work?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I remove all `Require all granted` (it's only for Apacvhe 2.4+) and paste:

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Also i move `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl` to DocumentRoot directory description